# Should I include interactions if I know they are not significant?

Tags: interaction

I am going to write a regression model including an interaction between X and factor Z, but there is evidence that there is no interaction between them.

Shall I put the interaction coefficients in to the model to predict Y or not?

Comment: What's the "evidence that there is no interaction between them"?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @xate.  For me it's hard to tell what your real question is here.  Can you make it more specific?  I.e., is there some particular aspect of modelling or interactions testing that you're getting stuck on?  Or maybe you intended this as a lead-in to a wider discussion of modelling strategies, in which case you might want to browse the site using search terms such as *interaction* or *modeling* or *variable selection*.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no evidence (meaning an insignificant t-test for the interaction parameter), then parsimony suggests you use the model without the interaction term.

Comment: I disagree with this as stated. In practice, there are examples of this sort of reasoning leading to a catastrophe (e.g. prediction in genetics). Parsimony is a tricky subject. It's not clear that the appropriate thing to do is to penalize complicated models simply because we lack power, which is what dropping insignificant terms does. A real issue with complicated models is just that they are hard to interpret, so we try to get to simple ones for convenience, but I might do that even if the interaction is "statistically significant" if I think a simple  model is a good approximation.

Comment: I also think that Radford Neal's thesis (1995) makes a similar point about parsimony, but much more eloquently. He is coming from a Bayesian point of view, but it is good advice for everyone.

Comment: @guy - could you describe one or two such "catastrophes" and tell how they were caused by dropping insignificant terms?  Dropping such terms is extremely common and I'm having trouble imagining how doing so is likely to be so very harmful.  I understand that low power may prompt someone to simplify to the point of neglecting a potentially important effect, but  if there is already some independent evidence for the lack of such effects,....

Comment: @rolando there is a well known phenomenon in genetic research. You can do some advanced variable selection to find appropriate genes that lead to a heritable trait, throwing away those that are insignificant. However, if you do that, your predictive power drops massively. Having all of those "insignificant" genes in your model actually has the net effect of improving predictive performance. This is the motivation behind "whole genome regression". For predictive power at least, I think leaving so much predictive power on the table classifies as a catastrophe.

Comment: @rolando2 For reference, these guys probably explain it better than I do (this isn't my field of expertise, I just heard about this particular problem from someone interviewing in my department): http://www.genetics.org/content/157/4/1819

Comment: @guy Thanks for the helpful explanation.  It's still a bit puzzling.  At some point each of us would draw the line and say, "With so many nonsignificant terms, we're overfitting."

Comment: @rolando2 sure, but that's what regularization is for :) Throwing at "insignificant" terms in a stepwise procedure is really just one brand of regularization (it's kind of like approximately using an $L_0$ penalty I think, doing a greedy search). But why not use, say, $L_2$ which uses everything in our final prediction? It might even be the right thing to do if we believe that the effects of the gene on each trait might be adequately modelled as a random effect with a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @guy Some good things for me to look into.  Thx.